# API headers not working in Python-Tornado when front end makes requests

Tags: python, react-redux, cors, pymongo, tornado

I've got a basic CRUD application, and I'm trying to get React-Redux on localhost:3000 to make requests to the backend, Python-Tornado (using pymongo for the database) at  127.0.0.1:8888. At first CORS was blocking all requests, but I found online that you can add headers to allow access to the API, so I did like this:

```
class UserHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
        Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
        'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE')
        self.set_status(204)

    def get(self, id=None):
        {...}

    def post(self):
        {...}

    def delete(self, id):
        {...}

    def put(self, id):
        {...}

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/users/(?P<id>\w+)", UserHandler),
        (r"/user/(?P<id>\w+)", UserHandler),
        (r"/users", UserHandler)
    ],
    debug = True,
    autoreload = True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    port = 8888
    app.listen(port)
    print(f" Server is listening on port {8888}")
    #start server on current thread
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Now my Front end is allowing GET requests, but POST, PUT, and DELETE are still getting blocked with the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/users/625f7194a10940f94e0b8f13' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow- 
Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied 
origin.
```

I've looked around at multiple resources and they all say to simply add those headers, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Change `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` in your react code or vice versa in your python code. They are not equal when comparing headers.

Comment: How do i do that? For example in Python it only asks me to specify a port

Comment: `self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:3000")` you specify more than a port here. Similarly, I assume your React code that you don't show here specifies the host as well.

Comment: oh yeah originally I just had "*" which should have done the job anyway. So how do i change from 127.0.0.1 to localhost in python?

Comment: Search and replace

Comment: I'm sorry I just started web dev a couple weeks ago I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean you find where your code has "localhost" and you type "127.0.0.1" instead. In many text editors you can do this easily by pressing `Ctrl+R` then type the phrase to find and the phrase to replace it with. This feature is called "search and replace".

Comment: Oh i see, but "127.0.0.1" isn't written anywhere in my code. I'm not sure how or where to specify that

Comment: Exactly... you need to put it

Comment: I dont know how or where

Comment: I don't know how I can be any more clear: replace "localhost" with "127.0.0.1".

Comment: Do you mean: self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http:// 127.0.0.1:3000")?
That doesnt work, now get requests dont work either

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I thought that was the issue. At least that is what the error message points to. What error do you get now with GET requests?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I had already had "*" from the start, I just made an error in the post, so I didn't realize you meant I had to change it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer by Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71933711/1925257) is correct: the request origin doesn't match the value in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

However, to keep things easier during development (while in debug mode), you can always allow the current request origin or just set wildcard values. This will also be useful if you want to test from multiple devices (as you won't need to reconfigure the origin header).

This is what I do in my projects:

```py
class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
        if self.application.settings.get('debug'): # debug mode is True
            self.set_dev_cors_headers()

    def set_dev_cors_headers(self):
        # For development only
        # Not safe for production
        origin = self.request.headers.get('Origin', '*') # use current requesting origin
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*, content-type, authorization, x-requested-with, x-xsrftoken, x-csrftoken")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'content-type, location, *, set-cookie')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Request-Headers', '*')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')

    def options(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # also set a 204 status code for OPTIONS request
        if self.application.settings.get('debug'):
            self.set_status(204)
        else:
            # perhaps do some checks in production mode
            # before setting the status code
            # ...
            self.set_status(204)
        self.finish()
```

Comment: Just added that in, now im getting: has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: @jmsapps Ah, yes, you also need to send 204 status code for OPTIONS requests. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your react code appears to make a request to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`, but your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` only allows `https://localhost:3000`. These are two different hosts as far as the headers are concerned. Just make them both the same.